# Use a non-master user to connect Athena to RDS Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-athena

I need to connect Athena to my RDS Postgres db.
I created a RDS Postgres database with a master user, Lambda connector using model from Application Serverless Repository and datasource.

I passed the JDBC connection string into the lambda environment variables which point to the main user and password of the db. This way I can connect.

Now I want to log in as a different user, not the main user.
I created a new user inside the DB and passed it to the lambda but I get an error.

> Failed to invoke lambda function due to
> com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaFunctionException:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication
> failed for user "rds_read"

Is it possible to use a user other than a master user?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-postgresql.html